# How to highlight multiple elements?

Tags: java, swing, highlight

As I read already some tutorials and code examples, I tried to highlight all values in a text with a searchpattern.

A code that works good on method search(), however in search2() and search()3 it throws a BadLocationException nonetheless it works with String.

I tried also one more solution, but which just highlight the first or the last element.

Could it be some syntax problem ?

```
package highlighttest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.Highlighter;

 public class HighLightTest {
  JFrame frame;
  JPanel mainPanel;
  JTextArea textArea;
  JTextField tf;
  Highlighter hilit;
  Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter;
  Color  HILIT_COLOR;
  Color entryBg;
  Color ERROR_COLOR;

public static void main(String[] args) {
   new HighLightTest().startApp(); // TODO code application logic here
}

private void startApp() {
 frame = new JFrame();
 mainPanel = new JPanel();
 mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 textArea = new JTextArea();
 tf = new JTextField();
 tf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new SearchListener()); //execute searchpattern from textfield

 HILIT_COLOR = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
 hilit = new DefaultHighlighter();
 painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(HILIT_COLOR);
 textArea.setHighlighter(hilit);

 mainPanel.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, tf);
 mainPanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, textArea);

 frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
 frame.setSize(500,600);
 frame.setVisible(true);
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   

}

class SearchListener implements DocumentListener {
 @Override
 public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
  SearchPattern s = new SearchPattern();
  try {
   s.search2();
  } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(HighLightTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
  SearchPattern s = new SearchPattern();
  try {
   s.search2();
  } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(HighLightTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {}
}
// search class that execute the search method
class SearchPattern {
 public void search() throws BadLocationException { // this method is short and works.
  hilit.removeAllHighlights(); // remove old highlights
  String s = tf.getText(); // get textfield string for searching
  Document content = textArea.getDocument(); // get text of textarea but as document
  //search 
  for(int index = 0; index < content.getLength(); index++) {
   String match = textArea.getText(index, s.length());
   if(s.equals(match)){
    hilit.addHighlight(index, index + s.length(), painter);
    tf.setBackground(entryBg);
   }
  }
 }

  public void search2() throws BadLocationException {
   hilit.removeAllHighlights();
  String s = tf.getText();
  String content = textArea.getText();
  int index = 0;
  StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(content);
  while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
   index ++;
   String t2 = textArea.getText(index, s.length()); //BadLocationException, why ? Is there another method which could be used ?
   int end = index + s.length();
   try {
    if(s.equals(t2)) {
     hilit.addHighlight(index, end, painter);
     tf.setBackground(entryBg);
    }
   } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
  }
 }

  public void search3() throws BadLocationException {
  hilit.removeAllHighlights();
  String s = tf.getText();
  String content = textArea.getText();
  for(int i = 0;i<content.length();i++) {
    String temp = textArea.getText(i, s.length()); / same as search2(), BadLocationException
    if(s.equals(temp)){
     textArea.getHighlighter().addHighlight(i, i+s.length(), painter);   
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use StringTokenizer for this.  If you read its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), you will discover that the second argument to a StringTokenizer constructor is not a search string.  Also, the documentation will advise you to use the String.split method instead of StringTokenizer.

Comment: Also, you should *never* write an empty `catch` block.  At the very least, call `e.printStackTrace();`.  Don’t you want to know if your code is not working?

Comment: Thank you, I edited it. I think I will use the mehod search(), it's the shortest and works. I was just testing with the others.

Comment: hilit.removeAllHighlights(); could be wrong, because there is an array of Highlighter,